# vega-altair in jupyter notebook: can't add labels to a scatter chart with a regression line or vice versa?

Tags: altair

I can plot a scatter chart with a regression line, and I can plot a scatter chart with a text label on each point. When I try to do both I get:

Javascript Error: Duplicate signal name: "param_1_Horsepower"
This usually means there's a typo in your chart specification. See the javascript console for the full traceback.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong or any workaround?

```
# minimal example

import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.cars()

scatter = alt.Chart(source).mark_circle().encode(
    alt.X('Horsepower:Q').scale(zero=False),
    alt.Y('Miles_per_Gallon:Q').scale(zero=False),
    color='Origin:N',
    tooltip=['Name:N']
).interactive().properties(
    width="container")


reg = scatter.transform_regression('Horsepower', 'Miles_per_Gallon').mark_line(
     opacity=0.50, 
     shape='mark'
).transform_fold(
     ["best fit line"], 
     as_=["Regression", "y"]
).encode(alt.Color("Regression:N"))


labels=scatter.mark_text(align='left', baseline='middle', dx=7).encode(text='Name:N')

#scatter + labels 
#scatter  + reg
#labels  + reg
scatter + reg +  labels
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I make all three objects individual alt.Charts(df), rather than make the regression and teh labels from the same alt.Chart(df) instance as the points, it works (see below for code).

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.cars()

scatter = alt.Chart(source).mark_circle().encode(
    alt.X('Horsepower:Q').scale(zero=False),
    alt.Y('Miles_per_Gallon:Q').scale(zero=False),
    color='Origin:N',
    tooltip=['Name:N']
).properties(
    width="container")


reg = alt.Chart(source).encode(
    alt.X('Horsepower:Q').scale(zero=False),
    alt.Y('Miles_per_Gallon:Q').scale(zero=False),
    color='Origin:N',
    tooltip=['Name:N']
).transform_regression('Horsepower', 'Miles_per_Gallon').mark_line(
     opacity=0.50, 
     shape='mark'
).transform_fold(
     ["best fit line"], 
     as_=["Regression", "y"]
).encode(alt.Color("Regression:N"))


labels=alt.Chart(source).encode(
    alt.X('Horsepower:Q').scale(zero=False),
    alt.Y('Miles_per_Gallon:Q').scale(zero=False),
    color='Origin:N',
    tooltip=['Name:N']
).mark_text(align='left', baseline='middle', dx=7).encode(text='Name:N')

scatter + reg + labels
```